# Version number for Visual Studio 2008 SP1 (professional)

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I'm trying to get jquery intellisense working per the instructions here:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/21/jquery-intellisense-in-vs-2008.aspx#7117822

I'm not sure if my VS patched right. The version number shows up as:
Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Version 9.0.90729.1 SP
I know it seems nitpicky, but I expect to see "SP1" at the end rather than just "SP"

Can anyone verify their version number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mine just says "SP" as well. What you should be looking for is the actual hotfix (KB958502) listed under "Installed products" (there's probably a whole bunch of 'em).

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I do have that hotfix though.